# INSERT & UPDATE issue with PDO PHP Mysql

Tags: php, mysql

I'm a student new to PHP and I have been trying to find a solution for this problem for days. Found all sorts of answers but I don't seem to find something for my exact issue.

I am creating an admin page for a football association as part of my assignment. All is going well until I'm trying to update scores (I re-started them with zero). I get a successful message but the DB is not up updated.

So I tried inserting the score instead, as part of a new fixture, everything else updated but the scores. So I know it's the scores the problem but I don't know why. I made them NOT NULL and then NULL to see if that was the problem, to no avail.

I had initially populated some of the fixtures with scores but after "updating" all of them became either zero or NULL as per the change above.

What am I doing wrong?

````
       if (isset($_POST["Update"])) {
       updateScore($_POST["FixtureID"]);
    }
    function updateScore($FixtureID) {
       try {
          $conn = new PDO("mysql:host=" . $GLOBALS['servername'] . ";dbname=e0912343_Fixtures", GLOBALS['username'], $GLOBALS['password']);
          $conn->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
    
          $statement = $conn->prepare("
    UPDATE Fixtures f
         , Scores s 
       SET f.WeekNo = :WeekNo
         , f.Fixture_Date = :Fixture_Date
         , f.HomeTeam = :HomeTeam
         , f.AwayTeam = :AwayTeam
         , s.HT_score = :HT_score
         , s.AT_score = :AT_score 
     WHERE f.FixtureID =" . $FixtureID);
    
             
          $statement->bindValue(":WeekNo", $_POST["WeekNo"]);
          
          $statement->bindValue(":Fixture_Date", $_POST["Fixture_Date"]);
          
          $statement->bindValue(":HomeTeam", $_POST["HomeTeam"]);
          
          $statement->bindValue(":AwayTeam", $_POST["AwayTeam"]);
          
          $statement->bindValue(":HT_score", $_POST["HT_score"]);
          
          $statement->bindValue(":AT_score", $_POST["AT_score"]);
      
    
          $result = $statement->execute();
          
          
    
            if ($result) {
         
                $GLOBALS['message'] = "The score was updated successfully!";
          } 
          
          else {
             
              $GLOBALS['message'] = "The score was not updated!";
              
                    }
       }
       catch(PDOException $e) {
          echo "We are sorry. A problem occured: " . $e->getMessage();
       }
    
       $conn = null;
    }
    ```
    
    if (isset($_POST["Insert"])) {insertFixture();
    
    }
    
    function insertFixture() {
        try {
            $conn = new PDO("mysql:host=" . $GLOBALS['servername'] . ";dbname=e0912343_Fixtures", $GLOBALS['username'], $GLOBALS['password']);
            
            $conn->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
            
            $statement = $conn->prepare("
    INSERT INTO Fixtures (FixtureID, WeekNo, Fixture_Date, HomeTeam, AwayTeam) VALUES (:FixtureID, :WeekNo, :Fixture_Date, :HomeTeam, :AwayTeam);
           
            INSERT INTO Scores (HT_score, AT_score) VALUES (:HT_score,:AT_score)");
    
            $statement->bindValue(":FixtureID", $_POST["FixtureID"]);
           
            $statement->bindValue(":WeekNo", $_POST["WeekNo"]);
            
            $statement->bindValue(":Fixture_Date", $_POST["Fixture_Date"]);
            
            $statement->bindValue(":HomeTeam", $_POST["HomeTeam"]);
           
            $statement->bindValue(":AwayTeam", $_POST["AwayTeam"]);
            
            $statement->bindValue(":HT_score", $_POST["HT_score"]);
            
            $statement->bindValue(":AT_score", $_POST["AT_score"]);
    
            $result = $statement->execute();
            
            if ($result) {
                
                $GLOBALS['message'] = "The fixture was inserted successfully!";           
            
            } else {  
            
                $GLOBALS['message'] = "The fixture was not inserted!";
            }
        }
        catch(PDOException $e) {
           
            echo "We are sorry. A problem occurred: " . $e->getMessage();
        }
        
        $conn = null;
    }
    ```
     ```    
    <header>
    <table>
    <tr>
          <td><h1>Football Association Admin Page</h1></td>
     </tr>
    </table>
    </header>
    
    <section>
       <h1>Welcome to the Football Association Admin Page</h1>
       <h2>Fixtures Maintenance</h2>
       <form method="post" action="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($_SERVER["PHP_SELF"]);?>">
       <table>  
     
     <tr>
    <td>Fixture ID: </td>
          <td><input type="text" name="FixtureID" value="<?php echo $fixtureid;?>"></td>
          <td><input type="submit" name="Get" value="Get"></td>  
     </tr>  
      
    <tr>        
       <td> Week No:</td>          
       <td><input type="text" name="WeekNo" value="<?php echo $weekNo;?>"></td>
       <td><input type="submit" name="New" value="New"></td> 
     </tr>
       
       <tr>
          <td>Fixture Date:</td>
          <td><input type="text" name="Fixture_Date" value="<?php echo $fixture_date;?>"></td>
            <td><input type="submit" name="Update" value="Update"></td> 
       </tr>
            
        <tr>
          
        <tr> 
         <td>Home Team:</td>
          <td><input type="text" name="HomeTeam" value="<?php echo $homeTeam;?>"></td>
          
          
        </tr>  
       
        <tr>     
           <td>Home Team Score:</td>
           <td><input type="text" name="Home_Team_Score" value="<?php echo $htscore;?>"></td> 
           <td><input type="submit" name="Insert" value ="Insert"></td>  
            </tr>            
        <tr>
           <td>Away Team:</td>
           <td><input type="text" name="AwayTeam" value="<?php echo $awayTeam;?>"></td>          
        </tr>
           
        <tr>     
           <td>Away Team Score:</td>
           <td><input type="text" name="Away_Team_Score" value="<?php echo $atscore;?>"></td>   
            </tr> 
         
         <tr>
          <td colspan=3><?php echo $message; ?></td>   
       </tr>
    
    </table>
    
       </form>
       
    </section>
    </body>
    </html>
     ```
````

Comment: when joining tables , it's common to indicate the way in which one table relates to another - unless the objective is a Cartesian product

Comment: Hi Strawberry, would you mind elaborating a bit more on "it's common to indicate the way in which one table relates to another", please? Do mean in comments or the way I'm presenting the code? - sorry, I'm a bit confused.

Comment: Your UPDATE says `UPDATE Fixtures f
[JOIN] Scores s` but you don't state the criteria for relating scores to fixtures, so *all* scores are joined to *all* fixtures (that correspond to $FixtureID)

Comment: Thank you Strawberry, the penny dropped! Once I actually got the criteria clear (which was FixtureID), the scores updated as they should have! Pity that I can't share the correct answer with you but between you and Kiko, I not only got it working but I understood it - which was driving me mad! Thank you again!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your form you use `Home_Team_Score` and `Away_Team_Score`, but after posting these become `$_POST["HT_score"]` and `$_POST["AT_score"]`.

These are clearly not the same, and therefore it cannot work.

Comment: Thank you KIKO, I misunderstood the importance of this! I changed it and now can see the scores but it filled all of the fixtures with the same scores! I thought it'd only affect the ID I chose?

Comment: @Nessy You don't select a particular row in the Scores table with a `WHERE` condition, so all rows get set.

Comment: Thank you so much for putting me on the right path!!